# Laravel Dynamic Ajax Dependent Dropdown

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, dynamic, backend

I Dont know whats wrong with this code but when i choose one of it no option value shown

Here my Blade View

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; float:left; width:250px;">
   <select id="division" class="" name="">
          <option value="groups">-- Division --</option>
          <option value="Male">Male</option>
          <option value="Female">Femmaleale</option>
    </select><br>
    <select id="participant">
          <option value="choosetools">-- Choose Participant --</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

here my script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#division').change(function(){
       var division = $('#division').val();
       $('#participant').html('');
        $.ajax({
          url:'getParticipant/{id}',
          type:'GET',
          data:{myID:division},
          dataType: "json",
          success:function(data)
          {

            $.each(data, function(key, participant)
             {
              // alert(city.city_name)
              $('#participant').prop('disabled', false).css('background','aliceblue').append('<option value="'+participant.gymnastid+'">'+'participant.FULLNAME'+'</option>');
            });
          }
      });
    });
  });
  </script>
```

here my route

```
Route::get('/getParticipant/', 'App\Http\Controllers\ScoreController@getParticipant');
```

here my controller

```
public function getParticipant()
{
      $getdiv = $_GET['divSelect'];

      if ($getdiv == 'Male') {
        $res = Magmodel::all();
        return Response::json($res);
      }else{
        $res = Wagmodel::all();
        return Response::json($res);
      }
}
```

Can Someone please help me so all data from model Magmodel or Wagmodel showup based on dropdown choose

Comment: What does `data`  has in it ? Can you show output of that ?

Comment: i have 2 table in database named magtab and wagtab with same structure it have colomn gymnastid, FULLNAME, CATEGORY, DOB

if dropdown division select male i want the dropdown option called fullname and value gymanstid from magtab table in database 
if dropdown division select female i want the dropdown option called fullname and value gymanstid from wagtab table in database

Comment: Why you have added `''` around `'participant.FULLNAME'` ?